# Inside a method is it the same to assign the return value to a variable first and then return it, with immediately returning it?

Tags: c#, performance

a)

```
public static List<T> Search()
{
   var test = GetList<T>(); // Potentially returning a huge number of objects
   return test;
}
```

b)

```
public static List<T> Search() => GetList<T>();
```

Does assigning first a big number of objects to a list variable, like in first case, has any impact in performance (memory,speed etc)?

My problem is that I want to measure the execution time of GetList(), without changing its code (don't have access to it) and without doing it in every reference of search. Thus, I am thinking of doing the below, but need to be sure that it won't have any negative impact anyhow:

```
public static List<T> Search()
{
   var time = Stopwatch.StartNew();
   var test = GetList<T>(); // Returns a huge number of objects
   
   Log($"Execution time: {time.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
  
   return test;
}
```

The code is for making the question clearer (if that is possible).

Comment: First of all, most likely both your methods will be jitted to the exact same machine code. Secondly both your methods literally move one pointer around (assuming not inlined). The list won't be copied, its size is irrelevant. Meaning the performance of those methods (except for the internal GetList call) is completely negligible, don't bother measuring that.

Comment: Why trust us, if in doubt use benchmark.net. additionally the compilers and jitting is very efficient and some times hard to reason about and easy to second guess. If you are worried about performance and have a performance problem best race your horses

Comment: *"Why trust us, if in doubt use benchmark.net"* -- @TheGeneral because everyone doing their benchmarks privately is not the way to share knowledge. Besides this, the BenchmarkDotNet aims at precision, not convenience. Not everyone is comfortable with letting their PC being tortured for half an hour (or more), to get a result that's an order of magnitude more precise compared to what they really need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Variables in C# are basically references so it doesn't matter how many objects `GetList()` returns, only a reference to the list will be passed around. This alone will make the code practically equivalent in terms of performance. Even more in release mode the 2 snippets [compile to the same IL:](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgTARgLACgYAYAEMEBYDcqqMAzNnJgMKYDeqmDm9jOAbJgDJgDOwAPABUAfJgDiAU2BdegoQAoAlMwZ0UjddgDsmAHbiA7px79hchOgsLCaxgF9lTGw1LYE7aSZEBlcQEMATgDGABYA+giyig6qGgwAbgGYwOK8mAC8YpIekVaYAPR5mAAKAPbJOsBgvhAQAJ5aYDoA5pi+mMEArk3iuh0AtgBG4v6YJQBmowMAVuKBwNwOLNrJvNbq9k6O6i5sRjLCmD4BIaFwOekiElLGOWuMRCi2QA=)

```
 .method public hidebysig static 
        class [System.Collections]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<!!T> Search_1<T> () cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x205c
        // Code size 6 (0x6)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: call class [System.Collections]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<!!0> C::GetList<!!T>()
        IL_0005: ret
    } // end of method C::Search_1

    .method public hidebysig static 
        class [System.Collections]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<!!T> Search_2<T> () cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2063
        // Code size 6 (0x6)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: call class [System.Collections]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<!!0> C::GetList<!!T>()
        IL_0005: ret
    } // end of method C::Search_2
```

Answer (score 1):

As bolov said in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73219013/9363973) it doesn't matter. And to expand on that, you can use a tool like [sharplab](https://sharplab.io/) to take a look at what code actually gets compiled (after syntactic desugaring) as well as take a look at the IL and even the actual JIT Asm generated, doing this with your example shows me that both examples are compiled to the exact same thing<sup>*</sup>

You can check the decompile C# [here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLQEsB2MIIA4D2ANrBACarIwJYDmqAxgZlVNsgDRkgDUAPgAEATAEYAsACgBABgAEAkQBYA3JMkCAzPKGyAwiWTIAPABUAfLIDek2bflaAMuiqmLAcQgwnVABQBKGztLWUC7OwEAdllMCAB3WW8YV39VCTCAX1CQtPDHZyTzWQBlaAQGAAsABQQCPFwYAE9ZAF53T0SUrKzNBPzXYtKKgEFDdFpMfyzrHLDbADcoBFkcKhbZDy98zpnZyOWUGFSMrp2exP6SxYqAEXQkBhhJnenZ8KiNjr8ju0yJdKA===) and the compiled IL [here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLQEsB2MIIA4D2ANrBACarIwJYDmqAxgZlVNsgDQwjpEA+AAQBMARgCwAKAEAGAAQCRAFgDckyQIDM8obIDCJZMgA8AFQB8sgN6TZt+VoAy6KqYsBxCDCdUAFAEobO0tZQLs7AQB2WUwIAHdZbxhXf1UJMIBfUJC08MdnJPNZAGVoBAYACwAFBAI8XBgAT1kAXndPRJSsrM0E/Ndi0oqAQUN0Wkx/LOscsNsANygEWRwqFtkPL3zOmdnI5ZQYVIyunZ7E/pLFioARdCQGGEmd6dnwqI2OvyO7TIl0oA===), I'll copy and paste the relevant parts of the IL here though:

(make sure to set sharplab to release mode)

```
    .method public hidebysig 
        instance class [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<!T> SearchAssign () cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2057
        // Code size 7 (0x7)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: ldarg.0
        IL_0001: call instance class [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<!0> class Class`1<!T>::GetList()
        IL_0006: ret
    } // end of method Class`1::SearchAssign

    .method public hidebysig 
        instance class [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<!T> SearchDirect () cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2057
        // Code size 7 (0x7)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: ldarg.0
        IL_0001: call instance class [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<!0> class Class`1<!T>::GetList()
        IL_0006: ret
    } // end of method Class`1::SearchDirect
```

([diffchecker to illustrate](https://www.diffchecker.com/qOho6Wf9))

<sup>*</sup>Well, technically a) is a method and b) is a property, but converting b) to a method shows this, plus the IL for a), b) and the method form of b) are exactly the same